# Combination of arrow tips

Tags: tikz-arrows

I want to have a tip, simultaneously a circle and an end line, in the center of the circle, like the figure [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4h8U.png).

I have tried with `shorten` command as in other posts, but the line end is outside of the circle.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[spanish,es-noshorthands]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepgflibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htp]
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0)--(4,0);
        \draw [|{Circle}-{Circle}|,shorten <=-2pt,shorten >=-2pt] (0,-.25)--node[below]{2.0}(4,-.25);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: f]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could try something like this

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[spanish,es-noshorthands]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{%
  newTip/.tip={Bar[sep=-2pt, width=8pt] Circle[sep=-2pt]}
  }

\begin{figure}[!htp]
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0)--(4,0);
        \draw [{newTip}-{newTip}] (0,-.25)--(4,-.25);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Result
[image]

Play with the width-parameter in `newTip/.tip={Bar[sep=-2pt, width=8pt] Circle[sep=-2pt]}` to adjust the height (width) of the line to your needs. There are also length and width-parameters (no radius as far as I know) for the Circle, but then you would need to change the sep-parameters as well.

Comment: Yes, I can change the parameters for the sake of ratio figure.